# Arduino error: does not name a type?

Tags: arduino

I have written a library, but have problem with error does not name a type. I've tryed everything, searched for couple of hours and no luck. Library is placed in the "libraries" folder of the arduino sketch folder. Please help!!! I am using OSX, but the same problem occurs on Windows also.

This is header file of the library:

```
#ifndef OpticalSensor_h
#define OpticalSensor_h

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MCP23017.h>
#include <Adafruit_RGBLCDShield.h>
#include <String.h>

class OpticalSensor
{
    public:
        OpticalSensor(int analogPort);
        void LCDInit(int columns, int rows);
        void SerialInit(int bitRate);
        void SDInit();
        double& ReadFromAnalogPort();
        void SDCreateFile(String fileName);
        void SDDeleteFile(String fileName);
        void SDWriteToFile(String fileName);
        void SDStreamToFile(String Text);
        void SDOpenFileToStream(String fileName);
    private:
        int _analogPort;
        bool _displayFlag;
        Adafruit_RGBLCDShield _lcd;
        File _MainRecFile;
        double _voltage;
        void _LCDClearAll();
        void _LCDWriteInTwoRows(String row1, String row2);
        void _DelayAndClearLCD(bool returnStatus);
};

#endif
```

This is .cpp file of the library:

```
#include <OpticalSensor.h>

Adafruit_RGBLCDShield _lcd;
File _MainRecFile;
double _voltage;

OpticalSensor::OpticalSensor(int analogPort)
{
    _analogPort = analogPort;
}

void OpticalSensor::LCDInit(int columns, int rows)
{

    _lcd = Adafruit_RGBLCDShield();
    _lcd.begin(columns,rows);
}

void OpticalSensor::SerialInit(int bitRate)
{
    Serial.begin(bitRate);
    _bitRate = bitRate;
    while(!Serial) {
        //wait until serial is not open
    }
}

void OpticalSensor::SDInit()
{
    // On the Ethernet Shield, CS is pin 4. It's set as an output by default.
    // Note that even if it's not used as the CS pin, the hardware SS pin
    // (10 on most Arduino boards, 53 on the Mega) must be left as an output
    // or the SD library functions will not work.
    pinMode(10, OUTPUT);

    //check if SD can be found and initialized. Print also message to
    //Serial if initialized and to _lcd if initialized.
   if(!SD.begin(4)) {
     if(Serial){
         Serial.println("Initialization failed!");
     }
     if(_lcd){
         _lcd.print("Init failed!");
     }
     _DelayAndClearLCD(true);
   }
   else {
       if(Serial) {
           Serial.println("Initialization done!");
       }
       if(_lcd) {
           lcd.print("Init done!");
       }
       _DelayAndClearLCD(false);
   }
}

void OpticalSensor::SDCreateFile(String fileName)
{
    //check if file allready exists, if not it creates one
    //and writes apropriate response to
    //lcd and Serial if they are initialized.
    if(SD.exists(fileName)) {
        if(Serial) {
            Serial.println(fileName + " already exists!");
        }
        if(_lcd) {
            _LCDWriteInTwoLines(fileName,"already exists!");
        }
        _DelayAndClearLCD(false);
    }
    else
    {
        if(Serial) {
            Serial.println(fileName + "Creating file " + fileName + "...");
        }
        if(_lcd) {
            _LCDWriteInTwoLines("Creating file", fileName);
        }
        _MainRecFile = SD.open(fileName + ".txt", FILE_WRITE);
        _MainRecFile.close();
        _DelayAndClearLCD(false);


        //check if file was created successffully and print apropriate response
        //to lcd and Serial if they are initialized
        if(SD.exists(fileName + ".txt")) {
            if(Serial) {
                Serial.println(fileName + ".txt" + " created successffully!");
            }
            if(_lcd) {
                _LCDWriteInTwoLines(fileName + ".txt", "created!");
            }
            _DelayAndClearLCD(false);
        }
        else {
            if(Serial) {
                Serial.println("error: failed to create file!");
            }
            if(_lcd) {
                _LCDWriteInTwoLines("error: failed to","create file!");
            }
            _DelayAndClearLCD(false);
        }
    }
}

//delete file from SD card
void OpticalSensor::SDDeleteFile(String fileName)
{

}

//open file, write data to it, and close file after.
void OpticalSensor::SDWriteToFile(String fileName, String Text)
{
    _MainRecFile = SD.open(fileName + ".txt", FILE_WRITE);
    _MainRecFile.println(Text);
    _MainRecFile.close();
}

//Open file to stream data to it.
void OpticalSensor::SDOpenFileToStream(String fileName)
{
    _MainRecFile = SD.open(fileName + ".txt", FILE_WRITE);
}

//Write data to file while file is open.
//Notice that you can stream data only to one file at a time!!!
//For instance, if you have two sensors that you want to
//write data to two different files, you have to use SDWriteToFile
//function!!!
void OpticalSensor::SDStreamToFile(String Text)
{
    if(_MainRecFile) {
        _MainRecFile.println(Text);
    }
}

//close file that you streamed data too.
void OpticalSensor::SDCloseStreaming(String fileName)
{
    _MainRecFile.close();
}

//clear entire LCD
void OpticalSensor::_LCDClearAll()
{
    _lcd.clear();
    _lcd.setCursor(0,0);
}

void OpticalSensor::_LCDWriteInTwoRows(String row1, String row2)
{
    //write first String in row1
    _lcd.print(row1);
    //set cursor to the beginning of row 2
    _lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    //write second String to row 2
    _lcd.print(row2);
}

void OpticalSensor::_DelayAndClearLCD(bool returnStatus)
{
    //if Serial or _lcd are initialized, delay for 2 seconds
    //and clear LCD
    if(Serial || _lcd) {
        delay(2000);
        if(_lcd)
            _LCDClearAll();
    }
    //terminate
    if(bool == true) {
        return;
    }
}

double& ReadFromAnalogPort()
{
    _voltage = analogRead(_analogPort);
    return _voltage;
}
```

And this is the .ino file where library is included:

```
#include <OpticalSensor.h>

OpticalSensor sensor(0);

void setup() {
  sensor.LCDInit(16,2);
  sensor.SerialInit(9600);
  sensor.SDInit();
  sensor.SDCreateFile("test1");
  sensor.SDOpenFileToStream("test1");
}

void loop() {

}
```

this is the error:

> In file included from Test_OpticalSensorLib.ino:1:
>   /Users/gaspersladic/Documents/Arduino/libraries/OpticalSensor/OpticalSensor.h:34:
>   error: 'Adafruit_RGBLCDShield' does not name a type
>   /Users/gaspersladic/Documents/Arduino/libraries/OpticalSensor/OpticalSensor.h:35:
>   error: 'File' does not name a type

Comment: See item 3 of [the Adafruit RGB LCD Shield FAQ](http://learn.adafruit.com/rgb-lcd-shield/f-dot-a-q) and follow the suggestions to make sure the Arduino environment is properly aware of the Adafruit library.

Comment: It is not just the Adafruit RGB LCD library problem, the problem is also "File" type that is part of the SD.h library, which is part of the Arduino core libraries. Actually it gives type error for each type that is not standard type e.g. bool, int, String, etc.

Comment: Ah, so it's probably an issue with including other libraries from within a library. I'd have to try reproducing this, which I won't be able to do today... (Presumably you're building with a test Sketch -- can you try maybe importing both your custom library and Adafruit_RGBLCDShield into your Sketch, and see whether the Adafruit error goes away?)

Comment: If I include "SD.h" library at the top of the sketch, error for "File" goes away. If I do the same for the "Adafruit_RGBLCDShield" some new errors appears.

Comment: Could you perhaps let us know what the new error(s) are, exactly?

Comment: If I include all the dependencies in a test Sketch file (e.g. `#include <Serial.h>/<SD.h>/<Wire.h>/<Adafruit_MCP23017.h>/<Adafruit_RGBLCDShield.h>/<OpticalSensor.h>`, I seem to reduce the errors to valid errors in your library (e.g. using _bitRate but not declaring it, etc.)

Comment: yes you are right. Some errors appeared because of my sloppiness. I think the answer to this question is now answered. I was missing #include statements in the main sketch file for the libraries that are also used in the sketch file. When I'll manage to rid of all the errors I'll post entire working code, maybe it'll help someone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The two includes you mention in your comment are essential.  'does not name a type' just means there is no definition for that identifier visible to the compiler.  If there are errors in the LCD library you mention, then those need to be addressed - omitting the #include will definitely not fix it!

Two notes from experience which might be helpful:

1. You need to add all #include's to the main sketch - irrespective of whether they are included via another #include.
2. If you add files to the library folder, the Arduino IDE must be restarted before those new files will be visible.

Comment: BTW I see you used bool instead of boolean.  Note sure if that matters, however.

Comment: Your first note ("add all #include's to main sketch") works to me.

Answer (score 2):

I got the `does not name a type` error when installing the NeoMatrix library.

Solution: the `.cpp` and `.h` files need to be in the top folder when you copy it, e.g:

```
myArduinoFolder/libraries/Adafruit_NeoMatrix/Adafruit_NeoMatrix.cpp
```

When I used the default Windows unzip program, it nested the contents inside another folder:

```
myArduinoFolder/libraries/Adafruit_NeoMatrix/Adafruit_NeoMatrix/Adafruit_NeoMatrix.cpp
```

I moved the files up, so it was:

```
myArduinoFolder/libraries/Adafruit_NeoMatrix/Adafruit_NeoMatrix.cpp
```

This fixed the `does not name a type` problem.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to this problem in a "}". I did some changes to my sketch and forgot to check for "}" and I had an extra one. As soon as I deleted it and compiled everything was fine.

Comment: +1, helpful, this was my problem as well.  The extra "}" was essentially terminating the loop( ) function, putting the rest of the code, and display.* calls outside the function.  One delete and compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know it this is your problem but it was mine.

*Void* setup() does not name a type

BUT

*void* setup() is ok.

I found that the sketch I copied for another project was full of 'wrong case' letters. Onc efixed, it ran smoothly.*emphasized text*

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do is adding this line to
 your sketch

```
#include <SPI.h>
```

before `#include <Adafruit_MAX31855.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

More recently, I have found that other factors will also cause this error. I had an AES.h, AES.cpp containing a AES class and it gave this same unhelpful error. Only when I renamed to Encryption.h, Encryption.cpp and Encryption as the class name did it suddenly start working. There were no other code changes.

Answer (score 0):

My code was out of void setup() or void loop() in Arduino.

Comment: I confirm Vitalicus's answer: one of the reasons for the error is the execution of actions (for example, assignments) outside of functions setup() or loop() in Arduino.

Answer (score -1):

Usually Header file syntax start with capital letter.I found that code written all in smaller letter

```
#ifndef DIAG_H
#define DIAG_H

#endif
```