# 'ControllerPosition' does not name a type

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide

In the following code, the avr-g++ (Arduino IDE) compiler throws the error: `'ControllerPosition' does not name a type`. What is the problem with the code?

```
struct ControllerPosition
{
  int y, x;

  ControllerPosition(int _y = 0x7FFF, int _x = 0x7FFF) : y(_y), x(_x) {}
};

ControllerPosition mapPosition(int input)
{
  return ControllerPosition((input % 10) * 2 + 1, (input / 10) * 2 + 1);
}
```

Comment: [Your problem is in another castle.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3d95a2e969d9f59) Sure you're not missing include statements or something?

Comment: Which line the error message refers to?

Comment: Yes. If you paste the very into a simple document of the Arduino IDE, it will not compile properly.

Comment: Line number 2. The error code is specifically: `sketch_feb29a.ino:2:1: error: 'ControllerPosition' does not name a type`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a problem with the code posted. The following works for me:

```
struct ControllerPosition {
    int y,x;

    ControllerPosition(int _y = 0x7FFF,int _x = 0x7FFF) : y(_y),x(_x) {}
};

ControllerPosition mapPosition(int input)
{
    return ControllerPosition((input % 10) * 2 + 1,(input / 10) * 2 + 1);
}

int main()
{
    auto testvar = mapPosition(4);
    return 0;
}
```

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635465/arduino-error-does-not-name-a-type) discussing a similar error in more generic terms.

Comment: Did you use the avr-g++ compiler?

Comment: No, I used MSVC. I've added a link to a more generic answer specific to Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the source of the issue. Arduino IDE finds the functions in a given file puts the prototypes of them at the beginning of a file, which means it puts the prototypes before the struct definition and the function uses the struct as its return type. Therefore the solution was to explicitly declare the prototypes after the definition of the struct.

i.e.

```
struct ControllerPosition 
{
  int y;
  int x;
};

ControllerPosition mapPosition(int input);

ControllerPosition mapPosition(int input)
{
  return ControllerPosition((input % 10) * 2 + 1, (input / 10) * 2 + 1);
}
```

PS: It is possible to declare the prototypes before the struct by making a class forward declaration `struct ControllerPosition;`.